# money_format php 2 decimals without currency symbol

Tags: php, money-format

I have this function:

```
money_format("%!n", $number);
```

This will output: 2200

How I have to edit my function to have: 2200.00
Thanks for the help!

Comment: from the php manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#refsect1-function.money-format-examples

Comment: Which locale you have se? that shows `2200.00` for me

Answer (score 2):

```
$number=2200;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format("%.2n", $number);    //2200.00
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/187696)**

**[PHP Manual for formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php#refsect1-function.money-format-examples)**

Comment: The number is correct, but I don't want the currency symbol

Comment: But theres no currency symbol. Do you see any on the fiddle?

Comment: Because I have to define setlocale at the beginning of the script, maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

in money format, use ".{numberOfDigits}" for the amount of digits after the separator:

```
money_format("%!.2n", $number);
```

or use number format, because you don't want the currency symbol anyway:

```
number_format($number, 2);
```